# How to organize cross-browser testing on browserstack

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumber, cross-browser, browserstack

I am executing a set of test cases on 2 browsers. By default, Browsersatck will execute the test cases one by one on each selected browser. This way is causing errors because the test cases are related to each other, and I need them to execute on one browser before moving to the next browser.

If I try two different runs, the test cases work on each browser separately but I need to find a way to only run once.

Answer (score 0):

Browserstack executes the user's test simultaneously so that parallel tests can be utilized and the user's test finishes in the minimum time possible.